# Как получить диапазон значений из генератора

Tags: postgresql

Иногда нужно вставить известное количество строк в базу.

Одно значение генератора можно получить функцией `nextval(generator_name)`, но делать N запросов для этого нерационально, а получать текущее значение генератора после вставки опасно «состоянием гонки».

Как предварительно зарезервировать диапазон значений из генератора?

В некоторых базах ([Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-genid.html)) есть второй параметр для этого.
Есть ли что-то подобное для PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

У функции `nextval` нет такой возможности.

Всегда можно просто получить несколько значений генератора в одном запросе, просто запросив эту функцию из источника нужного размера:

```
SELECT nextval('SEQUENCE_NAME') 
FROM generate_series(1, 100);
```

*Будьте внимательны, это не означает, что будут получены значения `[cur, cur+N)` — последовательность может разрываться. Т.е. придётся получать(fetch) результат запроса и использовать конкретные полученные значения.*

---

С другой стороны нет особой необходимости резервировать значения, если генерация нужна для автоинкремента первичного ключа таблицы.
Можно просто использовать `RETURNING pk_field_name` в INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (...) VALUES(...)
RETURNING id; // запрос вернёт использованное в поле id значение генератора
```